# *curious behavoir* why is font-size over width/height

Tags: css

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
 ul {font-size: 25px; list-style: none;}
 li{margin-left:0; padding: 0px 5px;}
 li a {width: 300px; height: 300px; height:300px; background:url(whatever) bottom left;}
 li a span{visibility: hidden;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<ul><li>
<a href="#"><span>some txt</span></a>
</li></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

why is here the **ul's font-size** making the width/height and not the witdth/height of the a ?

Comment: Mind putting this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? Its hard to actually tell what's going on otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@remy; `a` & `span`  are `inline element` so it's not take the `height , width , vertical margin & padding` so give

```
a , span{
display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an `anchor` tag is inline by default. Try adding

```
li a {
  display: block;
}
```

to convert it to a block; this will mean you can assign it a width & height.